# Get deploy key with GitHub API

Tags: java, github-api

When I use the GitHub API to get the deploy key, I receive the message:

> {"message" : "Not fund","documentation_url" : "https://developer.github.com/v3"},URL is https://api.github.com/repos/owername/reponame/keys?access_token=.\

Answer (score 0):

If you created the repository as private, you need to authenticate in order to see it. In this case, to prevent leaking of information about private repositories, the GitHub API returns a `404`